# Common-Source Stage with Diode-Connected Load

Tags: amplifier, analog, integrated-circuit

I have a question about the small-signal gain in a common-source stage with diode connected load.

[image]

I understand there are multiple equations for gm and the one you use depends on what relationship you are looking to investigate

I’m finding it hard to figure out which one to use.

**As you can see from above, I get a different small-signal gain depending on what equation I use. Why?**

Are they the same equation since the overdrive of M2 is completely self generated depending on how much current and overdrive M1 has?

Derivation of small-signal gain:
[image]

Comment: There are **two** modes of operation with this circuit: M1 is in saturation or M1 is in linear mode. M2 is diode connected so always in saturation mode. The "normal" mode of operation of such an amplifier is that both transistors are in saturation so that the gain is (in 1st order) equal to the ratio \$\frac{gm1}{gm2}\$

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Understood. I’m having trouble figuring out what equation of gm to substitute in assuming both in saturation.

Comment: Either formula (if correct) should result in the same answer. If not, your formula is incorrect or you're using it wrong. I think your term (\$V_{DD}-V_{out}-V_{th,2}\$) makes things complicated. I suggest to first draw the **small signal equivalent circuit** (that will simplify things) then re-try with the 2nd formula for \$gm\$.

Comment: Also, you don't really **prove** that \$A_v=-\frac{gm1}{gm2}\$. That should be done by expressing \$V_{out}\$ as a function of \$V_{in}\$ using the small signal model.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I just added my small signal gain derivation. I still can’t seem to see where I am going wrong in the second gm equation approach

Comment: AlfroJang, may I ask what kind of hardware (pen tablet) and softare (app and settings) do you use to create those sketeches? They look particularly neat.

Comment: @Sredni Vashtar I use an iPad + Apple Pencil with the GoodNotes app.